# Why isn't my image from android sdcard getting uploaded into a folder on the local server?

Tags: php, android, upload, localserver

I am trying to load a `picture` from my `sdcard` into a `folder` named `uploads` which is residing at `C:\wamp\www\uploads`. I have got some code from google and honestly I have not fully understood it. I have understood till how to go to the Gallery and pick up a file I did not get how the file loads into a folder in the server. So can anyone tell me how it works. And secondly my file is not getting uploaded into the uploads folder in the server. I have very little knowledge about php. So can anyone help me understand the code and fix the problem of the file not getting uploaded into the folder? My full codes are as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private TextView messageText;
private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
private ImageView imageview;
private int serverResponseCode = 0;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

private String upLoadServerUri = null;
private String imagepath=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

    btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2:80/task/UploadToServer.php";
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(arg0==btnselectpic)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
    }
    else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
         messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                  uploadFile(imagepath);

             }
           }).start();     
    }

} 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

    }
}
     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                  +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }


}
```

UploadToServer.php

```
   <? php
    $file_path="\wamp\www\task\uploads";
    $file_path=$file_path.basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) 
   {
  echo "success";
  } 
 else
 {
echo "fail";
 }
?>
```

Comment: done any basic debugging? Your php code is simply assuming the uploads will always succeed, which is very bad. There's a `['error']` paramter in $_FILES for a reason: CHECK IT.

Comment: Is your php upload script in wamp\www ?

Comment: ya it is in wamp\www\task folder

Comment: So it is not in \wamp\www\ but in \wamp\www\task\. Then the upload folder should be \wamp\www\task\upload.

Comment: @greenapps still nothing gets loaded into the folder

Comment: You should leave $file_path="uploads/"; And have a directory C:\wamp\www\task\uploads. And if your script is myuploadscript.php then the full path should be C:\wamp\www\task\myuploadscript.php and the url would be h ttp://myserver/myuploadscript.php or h ttp://myserver/task/myuploadscript.php depending on your document root.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an aversion towards 3rd party libraries, I would suggest using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to handle your http POST request.  It's a fairly simple library to use and it handles multipart form posts as well.  Also, make sure you've got

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In your manifest.

Comment: permissions are added

Answer (score 0):

Your destination folder for saving image of file_path on php is not \wamp\www\task\uploads. If you save your UploadToServer.php in C:\wamp\www\task then change the file_path in php code with this.

```
$file_path="uploads/";
```